# Catia select a feature from a specific instance in an assembly

Tags: python, vba, com, catia

Lets say I have an assembly like this:

MainProduct:
-Product1 (Instance of Part1)
-Product2 (Instance of Part2)
-Product3 (Instance of Part2)
-Product4 (Instance of Part3)
...

Now, I want to copy/paste a feature from **Product3** into another one.
But I run into problems when selecting the feature programmatically, because there are **2 instances** of the part of that feature.

**I can't control which feature will be selected by** `CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Add(myExtractReference)`
Catia always selects the feature from Product2 instead of the feature from Product3. So the position of the pasted feature will be wrong!

Does anybody know this problem and has a solution to it?

Edit:
The feature reference which I want to copy already exists as a variable because it was newly created (an extract of selected geometry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get help else where. Still want to share my solution. It's written in Python but in VBA its almost the same.
The clue is to access `CATIA.Selection.Item(1).LeafProduct` in order to know where the initial selection was made.

```
import win32com.client
import pycatia

CATIA = win32com.client.dynamic.DumbDispatch('CATIA.Application')
c_doc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
c_sel = c_doc.Selection
c_prod   = c_doc.Product

# New part where the feature should be pasted
new_prod = c_prod.Products.AddNewComponent("Part", "")
new_part_doc = new_prod.ReferenceProduct.Parent

# from user selection
sel_obj = c_sel.Item(1).Value

sel_prod_by_user = c_sel.Item(1).LeafProduct  #  reference to the actual product where the selection was made
doc_from_sel = sel_prod_by_user.ReferenceProduct.Parent  # part doc from selection
hb = doc_from_sel.Part.HybridBodies.Add()  # new hybrid body for the extract. will be deleted later on
extract = doc_from_sel.Part.HybridShapeFactory.AddNewExtract(sel_obj)
hb.AppendHybridShape(extract)
doc_from_sel.Part.Update()

# Add the extract to the selection and copy it
c_sel.Clear()
c_sel.Add(extract)
sel_prod_by_catia = c_sel.Item(1).LeafProduct  # reference to the product where Catia makes the selection
c_sel_copy()  # will call Selection.Copy from VBA. Buggy in Python.

# Paste the extract into the new part in a new hybrid body
c_sel.Clear()
new_hb = new_part_doc.Part.HybridBodies.Item(1)
c_sel.Add(new_hb)
c_sel.PasteSpecial("CATPrtResultWithOutLink")
new_part_doc.Part.Update()
new_extract = new_hb.HybridShapes.Item(new_hb.HybridShapes.Count)

# Redo changes in the part, where the selection was made
c_sel.Clear()
c_sel.Add(hb)
c_sel.Delete()

# Create axis systems from Position object of sel_prd_by_user and sel_prd_by_catia
prod_list = [sel_prod_by_user, sel_prod_by_catia]
axs_list = []
for prod in prod_list:
    pc_pos = pycatia.in_interfaces.position.Position(prod.Position) # conversion to pycata's Position object, necessary
                                                                    # in order to use Position.GetComponents
    ax_comp = pc_pos.get_components()
    axs = new_part_doc.Part.AxisSystems.Add()
    axs.PutOrigin(ax_comp[9:12])
    axs.PutXAxis(ax_comp[0:3])
    axs.PutYAxis(ax_comp[3:6])
    axs.PutZAxis(ax_comp[6:9])
    axs_list.append(axs)
    new_part_doc.Part.Update()

# Translate the extract from axis system derived from sel_prd_by_catia to sel_prd_by_user
extract_ref = new_part_doc.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(new_extract)
tgt_ax_ref = new_part_doc.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(axs_list[0])
ref_ax_ref = new_part_doc.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(axs_list[1])
new_extract_translated = new_part_doc.Part.HybridShapeFactory.AddNewAxisToAxis(extract_ref, ref_ax_ref, tgt_ax_ref)
new_hb.AppendHybridShape(new_extract_translated)
new_part_doc.Part.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a differed approach. Instead of adding references you get from somewhere (by name probably) add the actual instance of part to selection while iterating trough all the products. Or use instance Names to get the correct part.

Here is a simple VBA example of iterating one lvl tree and select copy paste scenario.

If you want to copy features, you have to dive deeper on the Instance objects.

```vb
       Public Sub CatMain()
    
            Dim ActiveDoc As ProductDocument
            Dim ActiveSel As Selection
            
            If TypeOf CATIA.ActiveDocument Is ProductDocument Then 'of all the checks that people are using I think this one is most elegant and reliable
                Set ActiveDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
                Set ActiveSel = ActiveDoc.Selection
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
    
            Dim Instance As Product
    
            For Each Instance In ActiveDoc.Product.Products 'object oriented for ideal for us in this scenario
                If Instance.Products.Count = 0 Then 'beware that products without parts have also 0 items and are therefore mistaken for parts
                  Call ActiveSel.Add(Instance)
                End If
            Next
    
            Call ActiveSel.Copy
            Call ActiveSel.Clear
    
            Dim NewDoc As ProductDocument
            Set NewDoc = CATIA.Documents.Add("CATProduct")
            Set ActiveSel = NewDoc.Selection
            Call ActiveSel.Add(NewDoc.Product)
            Call ActiveSel.Paste
            Call ActiveSel.Clear
    
        End Sub
```

Comment: I like the type check. But this is not what I want to do.
I want to copy a feature (like an extract) of a part. This part exists multiple times in the product. When i add the feature to the selection, Catia choses any (but always the same) instance of the part where the feature will be selected.

Comment: I see you were struggling with the positioning of the copied feature instead of selecting it. And also you put user to be the one selecting features, well you figured that out :)

I remember now that i used the LeafProduct also when i make mine sweeper game in Catia for my Macro courses to know which product the body i selected belongs to.

Comment: The feature carry the position based on origin in the part not the assembly. So if you are building Self made allcatpart you had to figure that out.

Comment: Catia Minesweeper :D interesting!